# GeoServer group layer of raster with different SRID

Tags: geoserver, group-layer

Can I create a group layer from raster layers having different reference systems to produce tiles (out of the group)?
Is it adviced to use one SRID for such layers/rasters (also COG used)?
Are You familiar with any issues that can appear on the GeoServer side after such a mix?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: do you mean a `Layer Group` or an `ImageMosaic` - its either yes or no depending

Comment: I mean Layer Group.